# White spot in the corner of the laptop when screen is turned off via software

Tags: laptop, display, standby, hp-laptop

So today I noticed a white spot (the shape kinda looks like water on a table).
The funny thing is that it shows ONLY when the screen is turned off via software (fn keys) and during the change from a graphic mode to another (like booting a game).

During normal operations is perfect, even on black background, when the screen is completely turned off it doesn't show anything.

It seems really strange, can someone tell me why?

Thank you very much

Comment: has the screen been replaced in past? or is it stock? The back of the screen might not have been perfectly clean when it was installed. Manufacturer would have made sure it was clean, but someone else might not have been...

Answer (score 1):

try running solid collors. if bios/diags have a lcd test see if it shows up at any time when that runs.  I have seen some dammage where either a thumb print etc only shows up when the screen doesnt have a picture on it.  as soon as the backlight turns on during boot or switching modes. some you can faintly see when solid color backgrounds are used and a specific color is chosen.

It could be as logman said that either when the pannel installed or even manufactured something happened. did this always happen or only all of a suddin.

I would suspect its phisical damage to the display some never get worse if that is the case and others eventually get larger and more pronounced. we see both cracked lcds and "water marks" when stabled documents or other objects get left in the laptop when the lid is closed.

Comment: This can help running solid colors, or test the LCD screen in general: http://www.dataproductservices.com/dpt